# spotify api returns 400

Tags: reactjs, axios, spotify

I am implementing the Search function using spotify api.
However, if you request get to api now, 400 will be returned.
I want you to help me with this.

```
    axios({
        headers: {  
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search',
        qs: {
            q: value,
            type: 'album',
        },
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

Comment: I believe if you're getting a 400 response, then the response body should contain more information about the reason for the bad request.  Can you also add the full response body to your question?

Comment: umm.. Can I tell you the parameter value required by the api document?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  I'm just saying that if the http code you're getting is 400, then you should at least also get a description of the error, as per Spotify's doco.  Have you see what the error description is?  https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/#response-schema

Comment: It just comes like this.Request failed with status code 400

Comment: I think your `qs` property should be `params`. See https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config. Axios does not have a `qs` request config option

Answer (score -1):

```
const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${value}&type=album`,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
        }
         axios(options).then((res)=>console.log(res))
        .catch(err=>console.error(err))
```

Comment: While this is probably correct for simple values, it's better to use the `params` object to ensure query parameters are correctly encoded (I didn't downvote BTW)

Comment: @Phil I agree with you as the op has 2 params (one of them is fixed also) so I just to write it all in one line.